# Multiple PUT methods in ASP.NET Web API 2

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to create RESTful service by using ASP.NET Web API 2. I've got a problem when there are two PUT method in my controller.

This is my model:

```
Subscription
- SubscriptionID (PK - Not Null)
- UserID (FK - Not Null)
- ReportGroupID (FK - Null)
- ReportID (FK - Null)
- IsSubscribe (Not Null)
- SubscribeDate (Not Null)
- UnsubscribeDate (Null)
```

User can subscribe per report group or per report, so I add another PUT method in `Subscription` controller. I can add a route as suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349247/multiple-put-methods-in-asp-net-web-api), but it will become RPC-style. Furthermore, it's been 4 years ago and use ASP.NET Web API.

I'm looking for solution in ASP.NET Web API 2 with RESTful-style rather than RPC, is there a way to achieve this?

UPDATE Config code:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: You can decorate your method with HttpPut attribute, look at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2 and search for HTTP Methods. Or by web api's convention, define your methods as Putxyz where xyz is your method name. Is this what you need?

Comment: post your config code. a route config like `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}` should do the work.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I'm using default config. By adding that configuration it works but as defined in http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api. "This style of routing is similar to ASP.NET MVC, and may be appropriate for an RPC-style API." I want to use RESTful-style rather than RPC, is that possible?

Comment: @SiddharthPandey I try to use Attribute Routing, `[Route("api/Subscription/PutSubscriberByReportGroup")]` and `[Route("api/Subscription/PutSubscriberByReport")]` in each method but the result is 404 the resources not found

Comment: By default, only one update operation can exist.