# web api get route template from inside handler

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I searched a lot before putting the questions here but the  more I search the more confused I get.

So I have created an handler and I am trying to get the route like this:

```
public class ExecutionDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (securityAuthority.VerifyPermissionToExecute(request.GetRouteData().Route.RouteTemplate, request.Headers))
        {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        }
    }
 }
```

*GetRouteData* returns null so I can't get to the RouteTemplate property but I can
see the route there in a list deep in the stack. I found so many different ways which one can use to get the route, but those methods evaluate to null as well. I am a bit lost on how to get something so simple done. I am using self host for development but will use IIS for deployment.

**UPDATE 1**

I forgot to put here what else I had tried:

```
//NULL
request.GetRouteData(); 
//EMPTY
request.GetRequestContext().Configuration.Routes.GetRouteData(request).Route.RouteTemplate;
//EMPTY
request.GetConfiguration().Routes.GetRouteData(request).Route.RouteTemplate;
```

The route works just fine, but strangely if I try to get the controller to service that request I get a 404... if I just step over that I will get to the controller just fine.

```
HttpControllerDescriptor httpControllerDescriptor = request.GetRequestContext().Configuration.Services.GetHttpControllerSelector().SelectController(request);
IHttpController httpController = httpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(request);
```

I am using autofac to discover all the routes which I am defining just like:

```
[Route("queries/organization/clients")]
[HttpGet]
public ClientInitialScreenModel GetClients()
{
    return OrganizationModelsBuilder.GetClientInitialScreen();
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

If I GetRouteData gets called after the line above, I am able to get the route template:

```
base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

var routeData = request.GetRouteData();
```

So maybe I misunderstood the whole picture and I cant get the route template before the handler that resolves which controller to execute for the request does its work... is that the case?

*For reference this is the handler I am working on:*

```
public class ExecutionDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var securityAuthority = (ISecurityAuthority) request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof (ISecurityAuthority));
        var configuration = (IWebApiConfiguration)request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(IWebApiConfiguration));
        var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
        var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();

        if (request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Equals(configuration.CommandGatewayUrl, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            var apiMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiCommandEnvelope>(request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

            if (securityAuthority != null && !securityAuthority.VerifyPermissionToExecute(apiMessage, request.Headers))
            {
                httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }
            else
            {
                var messageProcessor = (IWebApiMessageProcessor)request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(IWebApiMessageProcessor));
                var reponse = messageProcessor.HandleRequest(apiMessage);

                httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode) reponse.StatusCode;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reponse.Content))
                {
                    httpResponseMessage.Content = new StringContent(reponse.Content);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (securityAuthority != null && !securityAuthority.VerifyPermissionToExecute(request.GetRouteData().Route.RouteTemplate, request.Headers))
            {
                httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        tsc.SetResult(httpResponseMessage);

        return tsc.Task;
    }
```

**UPDATE 3**

The code runs fine in a non self hosting environment, so this is more like a self host issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Web Api still has a lot to improve. It was tricky to find a way to get this working and I just hope this saves other guys from spending all the time I did.

```
 var routeTemplate = ((IHttpRouteData[]) request.GetConfiguration().Routes.GetRouteData(request).Values["MS_SubRoutes"])
                                    .First().Route.RouteTemplate;
```

Comment: Haven't tested that one, but that would be strange to say the least, but anyway, a lot of things aren't really done properly, which I just hope ASP.Net vNext fixes.

Comment: Sorry I missed the answser. Your code works, I was referring to the other answer of @Shivan ahmady.

Comment: Ok, cause I was finding it really strange why my code wouldn't work on a base controller.

Comment: Works great for me; very useful to add to a DelegatingHandler to log all the routes that are in active usage, so you can make data-driven decisions about which API endpoints can be obsoleted without causing too many breaking changes.

Comment: Yep, that what I do as well. I also do access validation using delegates.. A role is composed of multiples routes and this way I can control the access to each route.

Comment: @taras.roshko LOL... I think this is all solved in the new ASP.net core

Comment: @Marco btw it does not work throughout entire request, i.e. If you resolve this at the very beginning - it's does resolve, but  during action run it just won't so you have to cache it somewhere which makes it even more gross. Checking out ASP.NET Core now..

Comment: If that's the case, because I haven't tried it out, just add a new request key and add it to the request object.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, but was able to get the route inside the message handler by the following:

request.GetConfiguration().Routes.GetRouteData(request).Route.RouteTemplate;

Answer (score 4):

The answer from Marco (shown below) is correct so long as there isn't more than one route defined with the same HttpMethod.   The `.First()` will grab the 1st route defined in that specific `ApiController`, but this doesn't ensure it grabs the correct one.  If you use the `ControllerContext` to get the Route, you can be sure you've got the exact endpoint you want.

Marco's:

```
var routeTemplate = ((IHttpRouteData[])request.GetConfiguration()
                     .Routes.GetRouteData(request).Values["MS_SubRoutes"])
                     .First().Route.RouteTemplate;
```

The code:

```
((IHttpRouteData[])request.GetConfiguration()
                     .Routes.GetRouteData(request).Values["MS_SubRoutes"])
```

actually returns a collection of `IHttpRouteData`, and it contains a record for each endpoint which has the same HttpMethod (Post, Get, etc)... The `.First()` doesn't guarantee you get the one you want.

Guaranteed To Grab Correct Endpoint's `RouteTemplate`:

```
public static string GetRouteTemplate(this HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    return actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Route.RouteTemplate;
}
```

I used an extension method so to call this you'd do:

```
var routeTemplate = actionContext.GetRouteTemplate();
```

This will assure that you get the specific `RouteTemplate` from the endpoint making the call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get route Data from request.Properties property and easy to unit test.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="System.Web.Http.Routing.IHttpRouteData"/> for the given request or null if not available.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The HTTP request.</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="System.Web.Http.Routing.IHttpRouteData"/> or null.</returns>
    public static IHttpRouteData GetRouteData(this HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {`enter code here`
            throw Error.ArgumentNull("request");
        }

        return request.GetProperty<IHttpRouteData>(HttpPropertyKeys.HttpRouteDataKey);
    }

    private static T GetProperty<T>(this HttpRequestMessage request, string key)
    {
        T value;
        request.Properties.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        return value;
    }
```

[Reference link of code](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs)

Answer (score 0):

```
var template = ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo?.Template ?? "Unknown";
```