# Why do POST requests map to this Web API action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I've been following along with a tutorial [here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) to get my head around authentication in Web API with OAuth.

I have worked on Web API before, where I named the methods to start with Get, Put, Post etc. in order that they were routed to depending on the http verb. I also know that actions can be decorated with attributes ([HttpGet] etc) to denote the verb that maps to them.

In the tutorial, there is an action on a controller that looks like this:

```
// POST api/Account/Register
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(UserModel userModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

     IdentityResult result = await _repo.RegisterUser(userModel);

     IHttpActionResult errorResult = GetErrorResult(result);

     if(errorResult != null)
        return errorResult;

     return Ok();
}
```

This method, as the comment suggests, responds to POST requests. I cannot see how the Web API knows that this action is for POST. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for Web API [Routing and Action Selection](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection):

> ...
>
> **HTTP Methods**. The framework only chooses actions that match the HTTP method of the request, determined as follows:
>
> 1. You can specify the HTTP method with an attribute: **AcceptVerbs**, **HttpDelete**, **HttpGet**, **HttpHead**, **HttpOptions**, **HttpPatch**, **HttpPost**, or **HttpPut**.
> 2. Otherwise, if the name of the controller method starts with "Get", "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Head", "Options", or "Patch", then by convention the action supports that HTTP method.
> 3. **If none of the above, the method supports POST.**
>
> ...

and the source for [`ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.cs`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/2fbe1eaa/src/System.Web.Http/Controllers/ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.cs#L294-L300) (line number 294-300):

```
...
if (supportedHttpMethods.Count == 0)
{
    // Use POST as the default HttpMethod
    supportedHttpMethods.Add(HttpMethod.Post);
}

return supportedHttpMethods;
...
```

You'll find your answer:

> *`POST` is the default `HTTP Verb` for action method in Web API.*

---

Also, if you search a bit more on SO, You'll find the following question:
[Is there a default verb applied to a Web API ApiController method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686841/is-there-a-default-verb-applied-to-a-web-api-apicontroller-method)

Although it's a different question, but the problem is basically the same as yours.