# Asp.Net WebApi. HttpPost is default?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Maybe I cannot find manual.

I found experimentally that **POST** is default acceptance verb if a method does not follow webapi naming convension (`Post~~`, `Get~~`) and does not describe verb attribute like `[HttpPost]` in webapi.

is that right?
is there any description about this?

Comment: oh downvoter, why...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a default verb applied to a Web API ApiController method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686841/is-there-a-default-verb-applied-to-a-web-api-apicontroller-method)

Comment: Upvoted. 1) google found yours because the title matched my natural search, 2) rather than downvote should have been a duplicate close vote.

Comment: p.s. I was glad to have a quick confirmation of this. The fact that I couldn't find it in documentation even *after* suspecting it was happening underscores the security risk this represents. I had put a public method on my ApiController base class to assist in instrumenting a code management task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's correct. If the method name doesn't map (through attribute, or convention) to a supported HTTP verb, then the default is POST.

Refer to the answer there

[Is there a default verb applied to a Web API ApiController method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686841/is-there-a-default-verb-applied-to-a-web-api-apicontroller-method)

Comment: Did you mean to link to another question?  Your link isn't very helpful at the moment because it actually points to this question.