# ASP.NET WEB.API 2 sets idempotent method as POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, idempotent

This method is idempotent according to the [http spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) which means it should be of type `GET`

```
[Route("GetLoadProfile")]
[ResponseType(typeof(List<ufnGetCustomLoadProfile_Result>))]
public async Task<List<ufnGetCustomLoadProfile_Result>> LoadProfile(int accountId, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    List<ufnGetCustomLoadProfile_Result> result = await db.ufnGetCustomLoadProfile(accountId, startTime, endTime).ToListAsync();

    if (result == null)
        return null;

    return result;
}
```

I do not specify that it should be `POST` and yet ASP.NET WEB.API 2 generates a `POST` method.

[image]

Why does this happen?

Comment: Why don't you just set it as `[HttpGet]`?

Comment: @Stan I could do that. Just interested why this method is generated as a POST when it should be a GET.

Comment: good question. already answered here though. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23687383/17447 its because `POST` is the default method

Comment: Your action name should start with "Get" or "Put" or "Post" etc to have the "Verb" selected on that criteria.  Otherwise the default verb for WebAPI is  "POST".