# (Edit/5) not working but (edit?id=5) working in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I just started learning MVC and I was trying to pass `studentId` as a parameter to an edit page. By default, when you click on the Edit link, it goes to:

```
 localhost:63348/student/Edit/5
```

but it doesn't work. it gives me this error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'StudentId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(Int32)' in 'WebApplication1.Controllers.StudentController'.`

But if I change it manually to:

```
 localhost:63348/student/Edit?studentid=5
```

it then works. Should they mean the same thing and work almost the same way?

Here's my controller:

```
public IList<Student>studentList = new List<Student>{
            new Student() { StudentId = 1, StudentName = "John", Age = 18 } ,
            new Student() { StudentId = 2, StudentName = "Steve",  Age = 21 } ,
            new Student() { StudentId = 3, StudentName = "Bill",  Age = 25 } ,
            new Student() { StudentId = 4, StudentName = "Ram" , Age = 20 } ,
            new Student() { StudentId = 5, StudentName = "Ron" , Age = 31 } ,
            new Student() { StudentId = 6, StudentName = "Chris" , Age = 17 } ,
            new Student() { StudentId = 7, StudentName = "Rob" , Age = 19 }
        };

    [Route("Edit/{studentId:int")]
    public ActionResult Edit(int StudentId)
    {
        //Get the student from studentList sample collection 
        var std = studentList.Where(s => s.StudentId == StudentId).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(std);
    }
```

Tried adding a specific route config but didn't work either:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "StudentEdit",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Edit", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Two things.  First, your route is malformed.  `[Route("Edit/{studentId:int")]`  You are missing the closing `}`.  Secondly, your route parameter is not identical to the name of the method parameter.  Case matters.

Comment: @Amy, The `DefaultModelBinder` is **not** case sensitive

Comment: You need to add `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` in your `RouteConfig.cs` before `routes.MapRoute(...)` to enable attribute routing, and add `[RoutePrefix("Student")]` to your controller definition

Answer (score 1):

You need to add attribute `[FromUri]` and correct the compiling issues (Provide closing bracket `}` and the argument name is not same.

```
[Route("Edit/{studentId:int}")]
    public ActionResult Edit([FromUri] int studentId)
    {
        //Get the student from studentList sample collection 
        var std = studentList.Where(s => s.StudentId == StudentId).FirstOrDefault();

        return View(std);
    }
```

Comment: FromUri is giving me an error. I changed the route making sure it matched in terms of case `[Route("Edit/{StudentId:int}")]` but still not working

Comment: @ElDj have you enabled attribute routing?

Comment: use it like this `[Route("Edit/{StudentId}")]`

Comment: Enabled attribute routing and removed the `int` part. Now, I'm getting a resource not found error

Comment: You're a step in the right direction.  Also add `[HttpGet]` (or whichever is the appropriate verb for your case).

Comment: Is't it supposed to be `[HttpGet]` by default? It still gives me the resource not found error

Comment: No.  Convention-based routing uses the method name to determine the verb.  `GetFoos` vs `PostFoos` for instance.  If you're using attribute routing, the action name can still be used, however, it defaults to [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686841/is-there-a-default-verb-applied-to-a-web-api-apicontroller-method)

Comment: If I enable attribute routing, I get resource not found for both `(/id)` and `(?id=)`. When I disable it, `(?id=)` works but not `(/id)`.

Comment: Changed my parameter name to `id` and it worked. Why didn't StudentId work tho? I even changed my routeconfig to `url: "{controller}/{action}/{StudentId}"` but was still not working

Comment: `[FromUri]` is for web-api (and its the default for a GET with a simple parameter anyway)